# Find URL in string and turn into a link

Tags: php, replace

I'm using [the code given on this page](http://www.michaeljacobsen.ninja/resources/article/find-url-in-string-and-turn-into-a-link) to look through a string and turn the URL into an HTML link.

It works quite well, but there is a little issue with the "replace" part of it.

The problem occurs when I have almost identical links. For example:

https://example.com/page.php?goto=200
and
https://example.com/page.php

Everything will be fine with the first link, but the second will create a `<a>` tag in the first `<a>` tag.

First run

```
<a href="https://example.com/page.php?goto=200">https://example.com/page.php?goto=200</a>
```

Second

```
<a href="<a href="https://example.com/page.php">https://example.com/page.php</a>?goto=200"><a href="https://example.com/page.php">https://example.com/page.php</a>?goto=200</a>
```

Because it's also replacing the html link just created.

How do I avoid this?

```
<?php

function turnUrlIntoHyperlink($string){

    //The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {

        // Loop through all matches
        foreach($url[0] as $newLinks){
            if(strstr( $newLinks, ":" ) === false){
                $link = 'http://'.$newLinks;
            }else{
                $link = $newLinks;
            }

            // Create Search and Replace strings
            $search  = $newLinks;
            $replace = '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$newLinks.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>';
            $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
    }

    //Return result
    return $string;
}
?>
```

Comment: check this out: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: Hi, maybe this help: $string = ((strpos($string, $replace) === false) ? str_replace($search, $replace, $string) : $string);

Answer (score 1):

I have change the replace part a bit, since I couldn't get the suggested regex to work.

Maybe it can be done better, but I'm still learning :)

```
function turnUrlIntoHyperlink($string){

    //The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {

        // Loop through all matches
        foreach($url[0] as $key => $newLinks){

            if(strstr( $newLinks, ":" ) === false){
                $url = 'https://'.$newLinks;
            }else{
                $url = $newLinks;
            }

            // Create Search and Replace strings
            $replace .= '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$url.'" target="_blank" class="external">'.$url.'</a>,';
            $newLinks = '/'.preg_quote($newLinks, '/').'/';
            $string = preg_replace($newLinks, '{'.$key.'}', $string, 1);

        }
        $arr_replace = explode(',', $replace);
        foreach ($arr_replace as $key => $link) {
            $string = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $link, $string);
        }
    }

    //Return result
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a whitespace identifier `\s` in your regex at the start, also remove `\b` because `\b` only returns the last match.
You regex can written as:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(?i)\s((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/"
```

check this one: https://regex101.com/r/YFQPlZ/1

Comment: Thanks :) But the problem is not the regex. It will find the links just fine. As I see it, it's the replace part. It will also replace html links that has already been replaced

Comment: when you check the space before any link, it will only match the un-replaced links because the replaced link has not any space at starting.
rest you can check in the above regex link, it only matches links without `<a>` tag not with `<a>`. As you are not using any whitespace while replacing links with anchor tag

Comment: That sound really cool, but it dosen't seem to be finding the link in my string when I change the \b to \s

Comment: You can keep `\b` and add `\s` after that.(it was working fine with \b earlier.)

Comment: Still not finding any links? `$reg_exUrl = "/(?i)\b\s((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/";`